How to access Cognito user attributes in the front-end?
Is there a way to access Cognito user attributes in the front-end using the AWS Amplify Authenticator API? I see that the JWT token which is exchanged with the front-end contains these user attributes, but I am unsure how to access the JWT token or the user attributes contained by the token through the Amplify API.
I would appreciate any insight anyone could share on this.  Thank you for your help.
